# Rabin Karp Algorithm Negative Hash

Tags: c++, algorithm, rabin-karp

I have this Rabin Karp implementation. Now the only thing I'm doing for rolling hash is subtract `power*source[i]` from the `sourceHash`. `power` is `31^target.size()-1 % mod`
But I can't understand why we're adding `mod` to `sourceHash` when it becomes negative. I have tried adding other values but it doesn't work and it only works when we add `mod`. Why is this? Is there a specific reason why we're adding `mod` and not anything else (like a random big number for example).

```js
int rbk(string source, string target){
        int m = target.size();
        int n = source.size();
        int mod = 128;
        int prime = 11;
        int power = 1;
        int targetHash = 0, sourceHash = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < m - 1; i++){
            power =(power*prime) % mod;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < target.size(); i++){
            sourceHash = (sourceHash*prime + source[i]) % mod;
            targetHash = (targetHash*prime + target[i]) % mod;
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < n-m+1; i++){
            if(targetHash == sourceHash){
                bool flag = true;
                for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
                    if(source[i+j] != target[j]){
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(flag){
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            
            if(i < n-m){
                sourceHash = (prime*(sourceHash - source[i]*power) + source[i+m]) % mod;
                if(sourceHash < 0){
                    sourceHash += mod;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: To make sure that it's in the interval [0, mod).

Comment: Is it because you're supposed to use an unsigned type but are using a signed one?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I've tried just flipping the sign but it results in a wrong answer.

Comment: no. the basic idea is to map an infinite space to a finite one. mod does this pretty well because it cycles back into the interval whatever the input number. On the other hand, if you used a large constant, there would always be some number that added to this large number would fall outside of the available finite space.

Comment: @user1984 It's still confusing to me because let's say even when we're making sourceHash positive in some way, even in a range of 0 to mod, other values still don't give us a good answer. I've tried taking as close a number as possible to the mod value but I just don't get why only the mod works. Shouldn't modifying the sourceHash in certain conditions create inconsistencies in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using modulo arithmetics `(mod n)` we have just `n` *distinct* numbers: `0, 1, 2, ..., n - 1`.
All the other numbers which *out* of `0 .. n - 1` are equal to some number in `0 .. n - 1`:

```
-n     ~ 0
-n + 1 ~ 1
-n + 2 ~ 2
 ...
-2     ~ n - 2
-1     ~ n - 1
```

or

```
 n     ~ 0
 n + 1 ~ 1
 n + 2 ~ 2
 ...
 2 * n     ~ 0
 2 * n + 1 ~ 0
```

In general case `A ~ B` if and only if `(A - B) % n = 0` (here `%` stands for *remainder*).

When implementing Rabin Karp algorithm we can have two potential problems:

1. Hash can be *too large*, we can face *integer overflow*
2. Negative remainder can be implemented in different way on different compilers: `-5 % 3 == -2 == 1`

To deal with both problems, we can *normalize* remainder and operate with numbers within *safe* `0 .. n - 1` range only.
For arbitrary value `A` we can put

```
 A = (A % n + n) % n;
```

Comment: @Mayank: `if(sourceHash < 0) sourceHash += mod;` solves the problems only *partionaly*: if `sourceHash` is too large you can face an integer overflow. Put it `sourceHash = (sourceHash % mod + mod) % mod;` and you are guaranteed to have `sourceHash` within `0 .. mod - 1` range

Comment: Okay, so if I understand correctly. Modulus with negative values can give different answers on  different compilers. So in case of say `-10%3`, the answer can come out to be `-1` or `2`.
In python3, `-10%3` gives `2`. In C++14 it gives me `-1`. So we obviously don't want the negative answer since that's incorrect. To make that negative answer appear as if it had calculated correctly, we can simply add the mod to get a positive value. It makes it as if it didn't calculate the negative modulus, but instead gave the answer like Python3 directly.

I hope my interpretation is correct.

Comment: @Mayank: you are quite right, the only detail is that `-10 % 3 == -1` is also correct, but not *normalized* which, technically, can lead to incorrect anwer (math formulae operate with standard `0 .. mod - 1` range).